# Adding row to a TableView from a different controller in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, controller, tableview

In this app that i am building i have in one stage a TableView and a few buttons. When i click on one of the buttons it opens a new window that is made of TextFields and a "OK" button. When i click on the OK, i need to insert that data into a Table.

So, i know how to insert a row into a TableView from a controller that controlles that TableView, but now i need to insert it from controller of another window. I tried everything, and it doesent work. I tried to get an instance of TableController and pass the data to its method, then i tried to pass ObservableList to a NewWindowController, and that also doesent work. I'm out of ideas. Can someone help me with this, i would appreciate it. Thank you.

Part of the code:

```
public class MainController {

@FXML public TableView<Film> tabel;

    public TableView<Film> getTabel(){
        return tabel;
    }
}
```

newWindow'sController:

```
public UnosController(){


    @FXML protected void insert(ActionEvent e){
        Film film = new Film(funosNaziv.getText(), funosZanr.getText(),Integer.valueOf(funosGodina.getText()));
        TableView<Film> tabel = mainController.getTabel();
        ObservableList<Film> data = tabel.getItems();
        data.add(film);
    }
}
```

That is my last try. Doesent work.

Comment: Do you have any code you've tried?

Comment: Please edit your question with that code. Don't post an answer unless you've actually answered your question.